# Spring+Jboss El Resolver JSF2, Target Unreachable, identifier 'user' resolved to null

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, jboss, xhtml

I have an old Jboss server(4.2.3) running spring 3 and JSF2 with primefaces. I can get my first login.xhtml to render properly with the jsf components but when I try to do any button click I get this "Target Unreachable, identifier 'user' resolved to null".

In my xhtml file I have some calls to my User bean, like for example:

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" style="width: 175px;" /></td>
```

My bean is annotated with @Component and @Scope("request").

I have looked at several other stack overflow posts but cant find one that helps me.

In my web xml I have:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and in my spring xml I have:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.my.package" />
```

and in my faces-config.xml I have added:

```
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
```

I have also tried to add a beans.xml as I have read that this might be needed in some cases. But now I'm out of luck so I turn to you. Does anyone have any idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: And you've dug deep into your stack trace to verify that the spring bean `user` was properly initialized within the spring context?